# Recently installed OS from Windows regretting please help

Tags: windows-7

**I  watch movies from www.usadisk.com daily religously it is Korean language. They require that I install their ActiveXSetup.exe and don't have an .exe for UNIX on the site for this:" DOS/Windows executable (application/x-ms-dos-executable)" Please help I am regretting installing this O/S Ubuntu it will not allow me to access these videos on the site stated above where I am a monthly member. I would appreciate a rapid response from Ubuntu community. I decided to trust in your word tat you are the best OS in the world.**strong text****

Answer (score 3):

The reason you could not open the .exe executable is that the utility you were trying to install was made for Windows, not Linux.  If you want to watch videos in a particular format, you almost certainly can, but you must use the correct utilities made for Linux.

As I understand the matter of ActiveX, that's a utility that works only with windows.  However there are EQUIVALENT utilities to allow users of Mac and Ubuntu to view the same media.  I've been using Ubuntu for 9 years and I've never encountered a video I could not open because I didn't have the right viewing software, or at least if I did, downloading the correct viewer took only a few minutes.

I have been to your www.usadisk.com page and found that my only difficulty was trying to watch any media without logging in.  Google translate could only handle so much, and so I gave up.  If you can direct me to a video of the type you are concerned with, which you cannot view currently, and which I can open without logging in, please direct me to it and I will attempt to open it. My guess is we can solve this in much less time than it would take you to reinstall windows.